# Root Certificate updates via Windows Update?

Tags: windows-server-2016

With the upcoming change of CA Root certificates for Amazon S3 and CloudFront I was doing an audit today checking that machines actually have the Amazon Root CA [1234] certificates installed, ref: [How to Prepare for AWS’s Move to Its Own Certificate Authority](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prepare-for-aws-move-to-its-own-certificate-authority/)

To my surprise most machines did not have any of the required certificates. I'm wondering what the requirements are for Windows Server 2016 to automatically download and install Root Certificate updates via Windows Update:

- These are standalone WORKGROUP machines, not domain-joined.
- Certificate Propagation (CertPropSvc) is set to Automatic start and is running.
- Cryptographic Services (CryptSvc) is set to Automatic start and is running.
- They have Windows Updates enabled and, supposedly, are completely up-to-date.

I read somewhere (sorry, I didn't keep the URL) that WinHttp requests can cause root certificates to be extracted from `crypt32.dll` and installed automatically. The following certainly worked for me for the "Amazon Root CA 1" certificate from a regular (not Run-as-Administrator) PowerShell prompt:

```
$winHttp = New-Object -ComObject WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1
$winHttp.Open('GET', 'https://good.sca1a.amazontrust.com/')
$winHttp.Option(4) = 0x3300
$winHttp.Send()
```

After execution the "Amazon Root CA 1" certificate had appeared in Certificates - Local Computer > Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates as well as in Third-Party Root Certification Authority > Certificates.

Likewise, requests to the following URLs added the Amazon Root CA 2, 3 and 4 certificates as well:

- https://good.sca2a.amazontrust.com/
- https://good.sca3a.amazontrust.com/
- https://good.sca4a.amazontrust.com/

Certainly I can script these requests across all the servers in the farm to make them install these certificates, but this seems like a big hack. It's also a concern - if they're not installing CA Root updates are they also not installing CRL updates?

So my two questions are:

1. Why aren't Root CA updates getting installed via Windows Updates like they are on Windows 10 desktop machines?
2. Are there settings that can enable the desktop-like behavior?